# What is the MaxDetect 1-wire bus?

Tags: c++, arduino, sensors, bus, 1wire

I bought this sensor:

http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Weather/RHT03.pdf

and the output is "MaxDetect 1-wire bus", What does it mean and how to use it? I tried to connect it to the arduino and program it but it's not working properly, I receive data of 1 bit constantly. I guess my code is wrong. Do I need to use the Wire-1 library for arduino?

```
int SensorVccPin = 8; 
int datapin = 6;
int bitcheck1;
int bitcheck2;
int temp[16];
int humidity[16];
int sensorcheck[8];

void setup()
{
  pinMode(SensorVccPin, OUTPUT);  
    pinMode(datapin, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{
    // This is the STEP #1
    digitalWrite(SensorVccPin, HIGH);  
  delay(5000); 

    digitalWrite(SensorVccPin, LOW);
     delay(15);


  digitalWrite(SensorVccPin, HIGH);  

  delayMicroseconds(30);   

  digitalWrite(SensorVccPin, LOW);  



while(digitalRead(datapin) == 0){

      delayMicroseconds(2);   }



   while(digitalRead(datapin) == HIGH)
{
delayMicroseconds(2);   }




  // STEP #2
  for (int i = 0; i<16; i++)
  {
    while(digitalRead(datapin) == LOW)
    {
      delayMicroseconds(2); }  

    delayMicroseconds(10);


  bitcheck1 = digitalRead(datapin);   // maybe store as an array
     delayMicroseconds(17);      // 50 sec pause  // 27us = 0 bit, 70us is 1 bit data
  delayMicroseconds(15); 
  bitcheck2 = digitalRead(datapin);

  if (bitcheck1==bitcheck2)
  {temp[i]=1;
  delayMicroseconds(28); 
  }
  else
  {temp[i]=0;

  }


    }

    for (int i = 0; i<16; i++)
  {
    while(digitalRead(datapin) == LOW)
    {
      delayMicroseconds(2); }  

    delayMicroseconds(10);


  bitcheck1 = digitalRead(datapin);   // maybe store as an array
     delayMicroseconds(17);      // 50 sec pause  // 27us = 0 bit, 70us is 1 bit data
  delayMicroseconds(15); 
  bitcheck2 = digitalRead(datapin);

  if (bitcheck1==bitcheck2)
  {humidity[i]=1;
  delayMicroseconds(28); 
  }
  else
  {humidity[i]=0;

  }


    }


    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
  {
    while(digitalRead(datapin) == LOW)
    {
      delayMicroseconds(2); }  

    delayMicroseconds(10);


  bitcheck1 = digitalRead(datapin);   // maybe store as an array
     delayMicroseconds(17);      // 50 sec pause  // 27us = 0 bit, 70us is 1 bit data
  delayMicroseconds(15); 
  bitcheck2 = digitalRead(datapin);

  if (bitcheck1==bitcheck2)
  {sensorcheck[i]=1;
  delayMicroseconds(28); 
  }
  else
  {sensorcheck[i]=0;

  }



  delayMicroseconds(80); 





  for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
  {
   Serial.print(temp[i]); 

  }
     Serial.print("  temp  "); 


  for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
  {
   Serial.print(humidity[i]); 

  }
       Serial.print("  hum  "); 

  for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
  {
   Serial.print(sensorcheck[i]); 

  }
       Serial.print(" check   "); 


    }



  }
```

Comment: "it's not working properly" is not a very good problem description. What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: The sensor is using 1-Wire which I don't really know how to program. I tried writting a program to receive some bits from it but it always gives me 1- bits out of 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave the VCC pin (pin 1) high the whole time. In fact, ideally, it should be connected to the power supply. It's the **data** pin (pin 2) that you should be pulling high and low to communicate with the sensor and it's the **data** pin that you should be reading. You will have to switch the data pin between input and output modes. Make sure you have a pull up resistor on the data pin because the sensor can only pull it low.

Answer (score 0):

MaxDetect 1-wire bus is specially designed by MaxDetect Technology Co., Ltd. , it's different from Maxim/Dallas 1-wire bus, so it's incompatible with Dallas 1-wire bus.

You can take a look to this:

http://tienda.tdrobotica.co/download/RHT03_programa.pdf

Best regards.